# multiplication in group by , dyslexia

Tags: t-sql

Now this is a simple insert query with one subquery and it's working perfectly:

```
INSERT INTO CSolutions..Report2  

SELECT  Nov.Chain, CG.Grouping, reg.code as regcode,reg.pname,reg.fname,reg.sname, SUM(NS.Currency) as sumeur ,   sum(ns2.kpl) as sumkpl,0,0,0,0


FROM CSolutions..NovSales NS,CSolutions..NSaleskpl NS2, CSolutions..NovCGroup CG, sales..reg_eng reg,
        (SELECT DISTINCT P.Code, Nov.Chain
        FROM Register..Pcy P
            INNER JOIN Register..TCustomer TC ON (P.Code = TC.PCode)
            INNER JOIN CSolutions..Novies2 Nov ON (TC.Code = Nov.TCode)
        ) AS Nov

WHERE NS.SpCode = CG.SpCode and ns.spcode = ns2.spcode AND Ns.PCode = Nov.Code
and ns.spcode = reg.code
 and ns.pcode = ns2.pcode

  **and NS.SalesMonth = '201205'
   and  NS2.SalesMonth = '201205'**


GROUP BY Nov.Chain, CG.Grouping , reg.code,reg.pname,reg.fname,reg.sname
```

This is derivate of the same query, but it's not working correctly:

```
INSERT INTO CSolutions..Report2  

SELECT  Nov.Chain, CG.Grouping, reg.code as regcode,reg.pname,reg.fname,reg.sname, SUM(NS.Currency) as sumeur ,   sum(ns2.kpl) as sumkpl,0,0,0,0


FROM CSolutions..NovSales NS,CSolutions..NSaleskpl NS2, CSolutions..NovCGroup CG, sales..reg_eng reg,
        (SELECT DISTINCT P.Code, Nov.Chain
        FROM Register..Pcy P
            INNER JOIN Register..TCustomer TC ON (P.Code = TC.PCode)
            INNER JOIN CSolutions..Novies2 Nov ON (TC.Code = Nov.TCode)
        ) AS Nov

WHERE NS.SpCode = CG.SpCode and ns.spcode = ns2.spcode AND Ns.PCode = Nov.Code
and ns.spcode = reg.code
 and ns.pcode = ns2.pcode

  **and NS.SalesMonth between '201201' and '201205'
   and  NS2.SalesMonth between '201201' and '201205'**


GROUP BY Nov.Chain, CG.Grouping , reg.code,reg.pname,reg.fname,reg.sname
```

This will give 5 times the 5 month sum amount,

I am a dyslexic and i have hard time to spot the error, I hope someone can help me ?? :)

Comment: "not working correctly" - please be more descriptive.

Comment: This will give 5 times the 5 month sum amount,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no join on the salesmonth in CSolutions..NovSales and CSolutions..NSaleskpl NS2. In the frist query this does not matter because you are only looking at one salesmonth. In the second query I presume there are multiple salesmonth's as you are selecting a range of value from each table. You are getting a cross join because of this of salesmonth's because of this.

Comment: THANK YOU! I tried to group by salesmonth which is not a solution I suppose.. thanks again

Comment: You need to add in  ns.SalesMonth=ns2.SalesMonth  this will make and  NS2.SalesMonth between '201201' and '201205' redundant but should force correct behaviour.